# Why cant change textbox text in client function SignalR

Tags: asp.net, textbox, thread-safety, signalr

I just start testing signalr and I am trying to add text to a rich text box after I got a response from my HUB class , but it doesn't work (no text is shown in my richtextbox) I don't know why...(the code run with no errors)

//server

```
public class ConnectByHub : Hub
    {
 public void testFunc(mas) {    
             string ans = mas + " got it";
            Clients.All.testFunc(ans);
        } }
```

//Client

```
 private async void connectToServer()
        {
            Connection = new HubConnection(LocalClient);           
            HubProxy = Connection.CreateHubProxy("ConnectByHub");
            try
            {
                await Connection.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                    
                return;
            }

            string msg = "Hello friend!";
            HubProxy.Invoke("testFunc", (msg)).Wait();
            // Option one - doesn't work
            HubProxy.On<string>("testFunc", (param) => Invoke((Action)(() => { MsgTxtBox.Text =         "something happened"; })));
            //Option two - doesn't work
            HubProxy.On<string>("testFunc", (param) => this.Invoke((Action)(() => { MsgTxtBox.AppendText("Something happend " + Environment.NewLine); })));

        }
```

Comment: The code runs with no errors? You're simply returning when you get them when you create the connection. You should log the error, or throw the exception rather than just returning. Also, have you added breakpoints to your code and stepped through it? Can you make it all the way through the code?

Comment: I used breakpoint it didn't the catch...and also insert another line to the catch with break point - it is ok,I checked that I get the output from the server and I do ,Even the "delegate" (Hubproxy.on<string>...) runs with no exceptions, still nothing changes in my richTextBox...

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the problem is trying to send a message from the same Async method (connectToServer) in which your listener is running.
I mostly used the same code from the question but moved a couple things around:

- Moved HubProxy.Invoke() out of the Async method and called it from a button_click event
- Called string.format() on the parameter

---

### SERVER:

```
     public class ConnectByHub : Hub
            {
                public void Send(string message)
                {
                    Clients.All.testFunc(message);
                }
            }
```

### CLIENT:

```
      // Added button event
       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string msg = "Hello friend!";
                HubProxy.Invoke("Send", msg).Wait();
            }


        private async void ConnectToServerAsync()
        {

            Connection = new HubConnection(LocalClient);
            HubProxy = Connection.CreateHubProxy("ConnectByHub");

            // Put the parmater in string.format()
            HubProxy.On<string>("testFunc", (param) => this.Invoke((Action)(() => MsgTxtBox.AppendText(string.Format("{0}", param)))));

            try
            {
                await Connection.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                richTextBox1.AppendText(string.Format("Unable to Connect to server ({0})", ServerURI));
                return;
            }

        }
```